# Sending Email With Swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, parse-platform, mailgun

how would you send an email with swift in an app. Like say for example your user want's to reset their password in a social media application with Parse(or not), but you don't wan't to use MessageUI because you want it to be automatic. I've done some research and found out that it can be possible with mailgun but i cannot figure out how to use it with swift and XCode 6. Can you please help me?

Comment: What have you've tried?

Answer (score 88):

Sure you can.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: ViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Source [Andrew Bancroft](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/)

Comment: from the question: "but you don't wan't to use MessageUI because you want it to be automatic"

Comment: when using In IOS9.2 simulator ,the view crashes with message "viewServiceDidTerminateWithError" . However other questions states that this is problem with simulator only and solution will works in real devices

Comment: Looks _very_ familiar https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/

Answer (score 7):

Parse supports both Mailgun and Mandrill out of the box.
See their [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mailgun)

You will need to write a CloudCode function, then call it from your app.

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters:[:]) {
  (result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // result is "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

Example code snippets to send mail using Mailgun.

```
var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
Mailgun.initialize('myDomainName', 'myAPIKey');

Mailgun.sendEmail({
  to: "email@example.com",
  from: "Mailgun@CloudCode.com",
  subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
  text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!"
}, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse);
    response.success("Email sent!");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error(httpResponse);
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a module i need to import? it is giving me errors

Comment: var Mailgun = require('mailgun');

Comment: I have that same code and i am still getting errors
also in swift you have to use "" for a string instead of '

Comment: No. This is a CloudCode function using Parse.com. It is a JavaScript-based language. Your question mentioned also using Parse, which is why I suggested this as an alternative. You could use Mailgun directly from your Swift code as well, but this will maintain better control over your API keys.

Comment: This is Javascript code.

Comment: Is there any good documentation on how to integrate Mailgun with swift? @picciano