# Sending email from table view cell Swift 3

Tags: swift, email, swift3

I have populated my table view cells with images from firebase. How do I detect which image I have tapped on and also bring the email composer with that image attached, as an attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are holding a reference to your datasource. In this case your firebase response.

`UITableView` has delegate and datasource methods to react on actions.

By implementing

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

You can be notified on the tap action with the `indexPath`. By using `indexPath.row` you can have the index for your desired image. Simply use this index to extract the image from your response/data source.

After this point you need to send an email programmatically. In order not to duplicate answers, you can follow this SO post.

[Sending Email With Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963514/sending-email-with-swift)

Comment: Would the email attachment be like this; let attachment = dictionary[indexpath.row]?